# Job Scheduling in SAS Data Integration Studio

Tags: sas, job-scheduling

i want to schedule a job in SAS-DIS. i tried the process using sas management console,bt an error is popping up saying scheluing server not found.
can anyone help me how to setup a scheduling server? or is it a software to be installed?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have scheduling servers already set up under "servers" in MC?

Answer (score 0):

I think a scheduling server is an extra package that has to be purchased.  Our BI setup is lacking that option and no matter what we can't seem to get it approved.  Check with your SAS server admin to see if the job scheduling has been enabled.  If so he/she should be able to tell you the process for getting it scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, without a scheduling server you still deploy your jobs and can either use
1. Cron and Crontab (in Unix or Linux)
2. Windows OS scheduler
to schedule jobs **manually** as this is the best option available if there is none. I know this can be very tedious and cumbersome , but can give it a try if you have less number of jobs to schedule.